# Codeigniter load captcha controller into index controller

Tags: codeigniter, controller, captcha

I new to CI and doubt about to CI controller, I have a pages controller which is an index  and use to load header, footer and all pages in a view, as below:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form', 'captcha'));
    $this->load->model('getdb');
    $this->load->library('javascript');
    $this->load->library('session');
}

public function index($page='home'){

    if(!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

    $data['sitename'] = $this->config->item('site_name');

    $data['library_src'] = $this->jquery->script();
            $data['script_head'] = $this->jquery->_compile();

    $data['results'] = $this->getdb->getAll();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('inc/mainmenu', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/sidebar', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
}
```

then I built a registration form which is use captcha library in the form, I found a sample  of captcha controller as below:

```
class Captcha extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{

    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper(array('captcha','url'));


    if ($this->input->post() && ($this->input->post('secutity_code') == $this->session->userdata('mycaptcha'))) {
        $this->load->view('process.php');
    }
    else
    {

        $this->load->helper('captcha');

        $vals = array(
            'img_path' => './assets/captcha/',
            'img_url' => base_url().'captcha/',
            'font_path' => './assets/styles/fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold.ttf',
            'img_width' => '200',
            'img_height' => '30',
            'expiration' => 3600
            );


        $cap = create_captcha($vals);

        $data['image'] = $cap['image'];

        $this->session->set_userdata('mycaptcha', $cap['word']);

        $this->load->view('pages/register.php', $data);

    }
}
}
```

here is my view named register.php:

```
<div id="content-wrap">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>">
    <p><?php echo $image ?></p>
    <p>Security: <input type="text" name="secutity_code"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

my problem is, how could I make Captcha controller load into Pages controller in order to process the function when I call url `http://site.com/ci/register` page? currently the page will show error as below:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: image
Filename: pages/register.php
Line Number: 65
```

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: which controller are you calling 'Pages' or 'Captcha' ???

Comment: @Kanishka Panamaldeniya, I called Pages controller by default, seems the Captcha controller doesn't invoke at all, whenever I go to url `http://site.com/ci/register`, variable '$data['image']` cannot pass to view.

Comment: yes when you invoke pages controller , you are not invoking the captha controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call to `pages` controller , the `capcha` controller is not invoking , instead of using it as a controller make it a library ,

load it in the 'pages' controller .

```
$this->load->library('Captcha');
```

then call to `captcha` library from your `pages` controller

```
$data['image'] = $this->captcha->index();
```

now the `captcha`  library looks like this.

```
class Captcha  {


public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

public function index()
{

    $this->ci->load->library('session');
    $this->ci->load->helper(array('captcha','url'));


    if ($this->ci->input->post() && ($this->ci->input->post('secutity_code') == $this->ci->session->userdata('mycaptcha'))) {
        $this->ci->load->view('process.php');
    }
    else
    {

        $this->ci->load->helper('captcha');

        $vals = array(
            'img_path' => './assets/captcha/',
            'img_url' => base_url().'captcha/',
            'font_path' => './assets/styles/fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold.ttf',
            'img_width' => '200',
            'img_height' => '30',
            'expiration' => 3600
            );


        $cap = $this->create_captcha($vals);

        $this->ci->session->set_userdata('mycaptcha', $cap['word']);

        return $cap['image'];
    }
}
}
```

hope this helps .

**UPDATE**

my mistake

use

```
$cap = create_captcha($vals);
```

instead of

```
$cap = $this->create_captcha($vals);
```

Comment: it returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Captcha::create_captcha() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\application\libraries\Captcha.php on line 31`

Comment: I knew that is not good practice to put in all captcha method into a view page, is there any others way to process the captcha helper?

Comment: Thanks @Kanishka Panamaldeniya, the error is gone, but the captcha image doesn't appear in my form, got to find what's issue in it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have error_logging set at the highest level
The error message you are getting is only a 'Notice' - its not worth worrying about.

See here for more info - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

However, it also looks like you do not have a 'register' function in your controller - you will need a function called register that does what you want if you want that url to fire.

Hopefully my answer is right or helps, because its my first answer on Stack!!